# Multi-url not working on netlify react app

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, netlify

I am having issues with my deployed react app on netlify,that works just fine on locally with no issue.  when i go to url like 
**www.mydomain.com/somepage** // everythin works fine
But when i go to url like 
**www.mydomain.com/section/article/2** //I am getting a balnk page

Can someone help me with this??

Comment: Check the CRA [deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#netlify) docs for what might need to be configured on the server. The general gist is that all page requests need to be redirected to the root index.html file so the React app loads and can handle routing/navigation internally.

Comment: I have done all this, but still not working.
I have placed a _redirects file in the public folder and the /*  /index.html  200 in it.
but still not working